# Highcharts check if a series is empty

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have this code in an AJAX success event, this AJAX fires after a date range is changed and updated, if there's no data to return I return a json array where empty == true.

If before the AJAX event fired there was data in the chart the nested if condition would fire and remove each data series.

The problem is if the chart initially loads with no data, then the user changes dates, the AJAX fires, see's no data the if condition is still firing and I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'series' of undefined`

Am I not checking if the chart series has data correctly? Isn't the if condition saying if the series length is greater than 0 run the while loop? How can I skip the while loop when there is no data in the series?

```
var chart = $('#chart').highcharts();
if (data.empty == 'true') {
    alert('empty');

    $('#chart').html( "<div class='empty-chart'>No data available for selected date range</div>" );

    if (chart.series.length > 0) {
        while (chart.series.length > 0) {
            chart.series[0].remove(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change order in your function, and use `destroy()` instead of removing series one-by-one:

```
var chart = $('#chart').highcharts();
if (data.empty == 'true') {
    alert('empty');

    chart.destroy(); //why remove all series, while you can remove chart to free some space and resources

    $('#chart').html( "<div class='empty-chart'>No data available for selected date range</div>" ); //now show some information about chart
}
```

Otherwise you are first adding custom text to chart container, removing all SVG elements. Then when you call `remove()` or `destory()` and Highcharts tries to remove SVG elements which doesn't exist.. and that produces error.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (chart.series.length > 0) {
----^^^^^--------------------
```

chart is `undefined`, where are you storing it? Make sure it refers to your Highcharts Chart;
alternatively, if you know it to be `undefined` in certain cases, just check for "truthy-ness" as well.

```
    if (chart && chart.series && chart.series.length > 0) {
```

**UPDATE**

HighSoft has a custom [module](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/blob/master/js/modules/no-data-to-display.src.js) for this!

Comment: epoch just above my condition I have `var chart = $('#chart').highcharts();`

Comment: When a series exists and a date changes they are removed properly

Comment: now what's happening is, if there is data in the chart, and I change dates, it clears but with this error `Uncaught NotFoundError: An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist. ` at `chart.series[0].remove(true);
`